# Dúvida sobre listas

Tags: java, lista, expressões-lambda, arraylist

Estou fazendo um programinha para cadastrar vôos e passageiros e alguns métodos como buscar lista de vôos, passageiros de um vôo etc. Eu quero criar um método que me mostre dentro de uma lista de vôos qual vôo tem mais passageiros. Meu projeto basicamente tem uma classe com Lista de Vôos, uma classe vôo (que contém uma lista de passageiros) e uma classe Passageiro.

```
public void listarVooComMaisPassageiro() {
       this.voos.forEach(p -> p.listarQuantidadePassageiros());
    }
```

Esse método eu consigo ver para cada vôo quantos passageiros tem porém eu quero saber desses qual o que tem mais passageiros.

Comment: Amigo, tu estás tendo algum erro ou resultado inesperado quando tentaste fazer isso? Poderias compartilhar mais detalhes sobre o que tentaste e quais os erros encontrados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo a sua dúvida principal: `Eu quero criar um método que me mostre dentro de uma lista de vôos qual vôo tem mais passageiros.`

Irei considerar o retorno do método `listarQuantidadePassageiros()` como `int`.

Você pode usar o método `Comparator.comparingInt` para ordenar de forma decrescente (`reversed`) para obter o maior vôo:

```
Voo voo = voos.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Voo::listarQuantidadePassageiros).reversed()).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).